# Laravel syntax error, unexpected 'routes' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to translate all routes. I'm using mcamara/laravel-localization package. My route looks like that:

```
    // Registration Routes...
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.register_link')/{plan?}, ['as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm']);
Route::post(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.register_link'), ['as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);
```

But i'm getting eror:

> syntax error, unexpected '{'

Whats wrong? Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the code preview that something is wrong with the colors. You have a tick ( ' ) in the first line you have to remove...

---

After you made the change over, you still have an issue and now I understood what was originally wrong.

This

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.register_link') . '/{plan?}', ['as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm']);
```

should be the right way to create the route as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `'` after get

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.register_link')/{plan?}', ['as' => 'auth.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm']);
```

Comment: Oh, my fault. Now i'm getting syntax error, unexpected '{', but everything looks good